passing powershell variable before running start-process
I'm receiving an error message when running a script...code is below with error message
$kk | & $exePath -ArgumentList $unregisterArgs -nonewwindow

$kk is the unregistering password that Fortinet prompts for
error parsing options: Option 'A' does not exist
i've tried to use invoke-expression which got a totally different error message.  the line above works when ran by itself in the PowerShell window.

also tried this "& $exePath -ArgumentList $unregisterArgs, $kk -PassThru -nonewwindow" and got the same error message.

if you're invoking an external command as: & $exePath there is no such thing as an -ArgumentList or as a -nonewwindow. Those are parameters of Start-Process and you're clearly not using it.

so the full string that works in the window itself is
$kk | & c:\program files\fortinet\forticlient\fortiesnac.exe -u

assuming $exePath = 'c:\program files\fortinet\forticlient\fortiesnac.exe' then $kk | & $exePath -u $unregisterArgs should work

got it!  Thank you so much @SantiagoSquarzon.  $kk | & exePath $unregisterArgs worked perfectly.

@MinhStewart Please copy this into a full answer and mark it as correct to help others.

Given that you're invoking an external command contained in a string ($exePath) via the Call operator & there is no such thing as an -ArgumentList or as a -NonewWindow, those are parameters of Start-Process.
Assuming the following works from feedback in comments:
$kk | & 'c:\program files\fortinet\forticlient\fortiesnac.exe' -u $unregisterArgs

Then this would work too:
$exePath = 'c:\program files\fortinet\forticlient\fortiesnac.exe'
$kk | & $exePath -u $unregisterArgs

-u can also be included into the arguments array, then splatting with array might likely work:
$exePath = 'c:\program files\fortinet\forticlient\fortiesnac.exe'
$arguments = @(
    '-u'
    # other arguments here
)
$kk | & $exePath @arguments


got it! Thank you so much @SantiagoSquarzon.
$kk | & exePath $unregisterArgs 

worked perfectly.
